# How to add custum attributes to js file loaded in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm practicing Angular and I tried to convert existing web application to Angular. I've some code that in HTML page ,like

```
<script src="js/rocket-loader.min.js" data-cf-settings="e61ee320c7ea21acda18972e-|49" defer=""></script>
```

I added **rocket-loader.min.js** in **"scripts": ["src/assets/js/rocket-loader.min.js"]** in angular.json and is loading, but the page actually breaking because `data-cf-settings="e61ee320c7ea21acda18972e-|49" defer=""` attributes are not available. I can't find any solution to my issue.

I tried this way to add the script but its not building.

```
          {
            "input": "src/assets/js/rocket-loader.min.js",
            "data-cf-settings": "e61ee320c7ea21acda18972e-|49",
            "defer":""
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in angular.json file, scripts is Array of elements

```
"scripts": [
          "src/assets/.../.../....min.js",
          "src/assets/vendor/.../..-stylist.min.js",
          "node_modules/ace-builds/src-min/ace.js",
          "node_modules/ace-builds/src-min/..-....js",
          "node_modules/ace-builds/..-../....js"
        ]
```

OR

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.setAttribute('data-attr', 'some value');
    s.src = 'http://somedomain.com/somescript';
    const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.appendChild(s);
}
```

if you want to add multiple attributes

```
.setAttribute('data', "icon: '.gif', url: '.html', target: 'page', output: '1'");
```

or you can repeat this line of code

```
 s.setAttribute('name', 'value');
```

Comment: For more clarification I edited my question. I actually loaded in this way. I want to know how to add custom attributes to js files.

Comment: see script tag dynamic implementation

Comment: Can you explain this answer? Please add some more clarifications like where to put this code etc... or can you suggest proper solution exactly from my question?

Comment: put it in component.ts file which is use this library, or you can add it in app.component.ts to connect it for all project

Comment: Are you sure this will work with Angular 8? I got so many errors in app.component.ts after implementing this code. Is there any import statement needed for this code?

Comment: I'm getting error **Property 'data' does not exist on type 'HTMLScriptElement'.** in this line **s.data = "some value";**

Comment: I check it in my Angular 8 Application

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201358/discussion-between-kiran-rs-and-boris-adamyan).